# Check if set of variables contains NULL in Oracle Apex PL/SQL

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex

What is the most efficient/cleanest way to check if a set of variables in Oracle Apex includes a null value?

The obvious answer would be:

```
-- this is a PL/SQL Function in a Oracle Apex validation
v_item1 := :P1_ITEM1;
v_item2 := :P1_ITEM2;
(..)

if v_item1 is not null and v_item2 is not null ...
```

But is there a cleaner way that I'm not aware of?

Comment: It's not so clear what you mean... is this a dynamic list of values ? A shared component ? If it is dynamic, then it is a select statement - how does that v_item1 fit in that ? It would be helpful if you gave a more complete example

Comment: I extended the question to make it more clear what is happening in the code

Comment: I think your code is just fine and perfectly readable (which can be very useful later on). Still don't understand how this is related to a list of values. Your example shows how to check for variables being null in pl/sql - there is no reference anywhere to a list of values

Comment: @KoenLostrie My impression is that the OP means "set of variables" rather than "list of values".

Comment: I adapted the headline.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the way you have it in your question is the best and most obvious way to do it, i.e.

```
if v_item1 is not null 
and v_item2 is not null
...
```

However, there is another option:

```
if least (v_item1, v_item2, ...) is not null then
```

This works because `least` always returns null when any of its arguments is null.

Conversely, if you want to check several items are **all** null:

```
if v_item1 is null 
and v_item2 is null
...
```

then you could use this:

```
if v_item1||v_item2||... is null then
```